# I am trying to add a recipe, which was never added before. I tried to call the favourites array and check if there is an id like that

Tags: reactjs, fetch, httprequest

I am trying to add a recipe to my favourites list but only if it's not in the list already.
I tried to fetch the favourites array and check for the same id, but it's not working. It doesn't take the array. When I console.log the array there is nothing. Please any help.

Here is the RecipeModel logic

```
    import "./RecipeModel.css";

import { Link, NavLink, useNavigate, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import React, { useLayoutEffect, useState,useEffect, useContext } from 'react';

import * as userService from '../../../services/userService';
import { AuthContext } from "../../../contexts/AuthContext";
import * as likeService from '../../../services/likeService';
import useRecipeState from "../../EditRecipe/RecipeState";


const RecipeModel = ({recipe}) => {

    const history = useNavigate();
    const {user} = useContext(AuthContext);
    const {recipeId} = useParams();
    const [likes,setLikes] = useRecipeState(recipeId);
    const [favourites,setFavourites] = useState([]);


    useEffect(() => {
        likeService.getLikes(recipe._id)
            .then(likes => {
                setLikes(state => ({...state, likes}))
            })
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        userService.yourFavourites(user._id)
        .then(result => {
            setFavourites(result);
        })
    },[]);

    const valid = !(favourites.some(i => i._id === recipe._id));

    if(valid) {

        const HandleFavourite = (e) =>  {

            e.preventDefault();
    
    
            console.log(`Recipe ${recipe._id}`);
         
                const name = recipe.name;
                const time = recipe.time;
                const imageUrl = recipe.imageUrl;
                const ingredients = recipe.ingredients;
                const instructions = recipe.instructions;
    
                
            userService.addFavourite({
                name,
                time,
                imageUrl,
                ingredients,
                instructions
            },user.accessToken)
             .then(result => {
                console.log(result);
                console.log(index);
                console.log(user._id);
                history('/favourites');
            })
    
        }

    }
    


    const likeButtonClick = () => {

        if (user._id === recipe._ownerId) {
            return;
        }

        if (recipel.likes.includes(user._id)) {
            return;
        }

        likeService.like(user._id, recipeId)
            .then(() => {
                setLikes(state => ({...state, likes: [...state.likes, user._id]}));
                console.log('liked');
            });
    };
    
    
 
   

    return (
        <article className="articles">
            <img className="img2" src={recipe.imageUrl}/>
            <h1>{recipe.name}</h1>
            <p className="cut-text">{recipe.instructions}</p>
            <div className="btns1">
            <Link  smooth= "true" className="btnd" to={`/recipe-details/recipe-number:${recipe._id}`}>Details</Link>
            <button className="like" onClick={likeButtonClick} > <i className="fas fa-solid fa-thumbs-up"></i>  {likes.likes?.length || 0}</button>
            <button className="favour" onClick={HandleFavourite} ><i className="fas fa-solid fa-heart-circle-plus"></i></button>
            </div>
        </article>
    );

};

export default RecipeModel;
```

Thats the userService logic :

```
   export const addFavourite = async (recipeData,token) => {
    let response = await fetch(`${baseUrl}/favourites`, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'content-type': 'application/json',
            'X-Authorization': token,
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(recipeData)
    });
    
    let  result = await response.json();

    
    return result;
};

export const getAllFavourites = async () => {
    let response = await fetch(`${baseUrl}/favourites`)

    let recipes = await response.json();

    let result = Object.values(recipes);

    return result;
}

export const removeFavourite = (recipeId, token) => {
    return fetch(`${baseUrl}/favourites/${recipeId}`, {
        method: 'DELETE',
        headers: {
            'X-Authorization': token,
        },
    }).then(res => res.json());
};

export const getOneFav = (recipeId) => {
    return fetch(`${baseUrl}/favourites/${recipeId}`)
        .then(res => res.json())
};

export const yourFavourites = (ownerId) => {
    let query = encodeURIComponent(`_ownerId="${ownerId}"`);

    return request.get(`${baseUrl}/favourites?where=${query}`);
};
```

Comment: Can you show in the code where exactly you are trying to get an array and where is it empty? Where is the console.log you are talking about? Im not even sure your app will run due to you cannot declare functions in `if` scope and bind them to jsx template, `HandleFavourite` i mean, it will be undefined due to not in scope of the component. Next - ` if (recipel.likes.includes(user._id))` why is it `recipel`? typo?

Comment: So i figured out that the id based adding won't work, because i create a new recipe with a new id, so it will never have two identical id, so now i am trying to compare the whole  data, to see if everything is matching, That's the Recipe Model logic, its exact code where i am calling my user Service to fetch all of the favourite recipes.